# No usable value for availableFrom

Tags: json, scala, deserialization

I use the library:

> "net.liftweb" %% "lift-json" % "3.4.3"

For some reason, I get this error:

> ERROR 2021-07-16 23:50:38,743
> [CommunicationService-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5]
> akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy - No usable value for availableFrom
> Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor args= arg
> types= constructor=public
> org.joda.time.DateTime(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)
> net.liftweb.json.MappingException: No usable value for availableFrom
> Parsed JSON values do not match with class constructor args= arg
> types= constructor=public
> org.joda.time.DateTime(int,int,int,int,int,int,int,org.joda.time.DateTimeZone)
> at net.liftweb.json.Meta$.fail(Meta.scala:227)  at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.mkValue$1(Extraction.scala:438)  at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.build$1(Extraction.scala:385)    at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.$anonfun$extract0$13(Extraction.scala:260)
> at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:287)  at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.instantiate$1(Extraction.scala:260)  at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.newInstance$1(Extraction.scala:308)  at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.build$1(Extraction.scala:379)    at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract0(Extraction.scala:444)   at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract0(Extraction.scala:206)   at
> net.liftweb.json.Extraction$.extract(Extraction.scala:43)     at
> net.liftweb.json.JsonAST$JValue.extract(JsonAST.scala:704)    at
> net.liftweb.json.Serialization$.read(Serialization.scala:62)

But I can't understand the reasons and how to fix it.

I checked the presence of a constructor without parameters for the type and it is there:

```
public DateTime() {
    super();
}
```

I call the library like this:

```
read[models.ChannelMessage](json)
```

The class looks like this:

```
case class ChannelMessage(
                           channelId: ChannelId,
                           message: String,
                           id: UUID = UUIDs.timeBased(),
                           ttl: Option[FiniteDuration],
                           attributes: Map[String, String],
                           tags: Set[String],
                           availableFrom: Option[DateTime],
                           availableTo: Option[DateTime],
                           persistent: Boolean)
```

Why doesn't it work?)

Comment: the problem is in the Joda Datetime json decoder. It can´t ceate a Datetime object form the string in the availableFrom  field

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez how i can fix it? It worked with early version...